# ASP.NET MVC - DisplayFormat returns currency based on computer setting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using the following line in my model to format value in currency.

However, i found an issue  - it returns currency symbol based on computer setting. 
**e.g.** in my case it returns $ but person having UK setting returns pound sign

```
DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")
```

is there any workaround for this?
please advise.

Comment: What do you want? You want to fix the currency for all users?

Comment: Yes, i want to have fixed my currency for all users i.e. USD

Comment: `DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")` will display the currency based on the culture of the server so if the culture is `en-US` the the page will **always** render `$0.00`. It makes no difference what the culture is on the browser that receives the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fix the currency for all users of your application then in your web.config (file at the root of your project), localize the `<system.web>` element and in it add the following element :

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" enableClientBasedCulture="false"/>
```